# Get the Text of clicked item in gridView

Tags: android

I have a gridView in which every cell contains an ImageView and a TextView. When the user clicks on an item, I want to take the text of TextView in position which the user clicked. I tried the code below, but every time I take the first element.

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        ViewGroup gridChild = (ViewGroup) grid.getChildAt(position);
        int childSize = gridChild.getChildCount();

        for(int k = 0; k < childSize; k++) {
           if(gridChild.getChildAt(k) instanceof TextView ){
                  TextView temp = (TextView) findViewById(gridChild.getChildAt(k).getId());
                  stationId = temp.getText().toString();
                  Log.i("stationId", stationId);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)`

Comment: when i used the above I take  java.lang.NullPointerException in this line TextView temp = (TextView) findViewById(gridChild.getChildAt(k).getId());

Comment: it doesn't exactly  look what I wrote, does it?

Comment: I mean that I exchange the line ViewGroup gridChild = (ViewGroup) grid.getChildAt(position); with the  ViewGroup gridChild = (ViewGroup) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); and then I take  java.lang.NullPointerException in the line TextView temp = (TextView) findViewById(gridChild.getChildAt(k).getId());

Comment: Casting to ViewGroup is wrong. What kind of adapter are you using?

Comment: custom adapter. I extend the BaseAdapter.

Comment: and what is getItem returning ?

Comment: Finally i fixed the problem. The problem was in the cast of the line TextView temp = (TextView) findViewById(gridChild.getChildAt(k).getId());

Answer (score 2):

```
 yourGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
               long id) {

         String clickedText = yourGridView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());


       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridView_item, null);
        TextView tw1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
ImageView im = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ImgaeView);

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
String getText=tw1.getText();

            }

        return rowView;
    }
```

Comment: I have override the getView() before and I can't use the above code.

Comment: add the above clicklistener of the textview with the getview() you have used.

Comment: it doesn't work and it is logic not to work. When the user clicks on an item of gridView he doesn't click the TextView.

Comment: see now i have changed a little bit

Comment: i used setonclicklistener on rowView so u can use to get the text

Answer (score 0):

gridItems is a class holding an array list of items in the gridView. use array list user define method getGridItems() to get the array List of gridItems.On which which then call the method .get(position) passing the position index that fired the event as a parameter to .get(position) to retrieve which ever properties associated with am item of the GridIemsList

```
public class GridItemsList {
private ArrayList<GridItem> gridItems = new ArrayList<GridItem>();

public GridItemsList() {

}

public ArrayList<GridItem> getGridItems() {
    return gridItems;
}

public void addToList(GridItem gridItem) {
    this.gridItems.add(gridItem);
}



  //ManinActivity.java                                       
  private GridItemsList gridItems; 
    //dump some data to arrayList
   gridItems = new GridItemsList();
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
        GridItem item = new GridItem();
        if((i%2)==0)
        {
            item.setImageId(R.drawable.family);
            item.setName("Family");
        }
        else {
            item.setImageId(R.drawable.love);
            item.setName("Love");
        }


        gridItems.addToList(item);


    }
    CustomGrid adapter = new 
    CustomGrid(MainActivity.this,gridItems.getGridItems());
    grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);                                         

   /***
     *  create a Toast
     */                                         
  grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            String clickedText = gridItems.getGridItems().get(position).getName();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + clickedText  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
```